# inputで何も入れずにenterのみを押した場合にErrorを発生させ、その後もループ処理を続ける方法

Tags: python

input()でenterのみを押した際にerrorを発生させその後もループを続けさせる方法を知りたいです

```
while True:
try:
    for c in input("好きな数字を入れてください→ "):
        int(c)
    break
except:
    print("数字以外が入力されています")
```

Comment: 解決しました！ありがとうございました

Comment: 解決できて良かったです。先程気が付いたのですが、回答の `int(str(c))` の部分は `int(c)` で充分でした（`str()` は不要）。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
while True:
  try:
    c = input("好きな数字を入れてください→ ")
    int(str(c))
    break
  except ValueError:
    print("数字以外が入力されています")
  except EOFError:
    break
```